# How to understand the webpack config in react-router project

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, react-router

I am learning react-router dynamic routing from this link https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/blob/master/docs/guides/DynamicRouting.md. The huge-apps project is the one I am looking into. I cloned the react-router git repo from https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router and followed the instruction to set it up. Everything works fine here. But I don't understand some parts of the configuration in webpack configuration under examples directory.

Below is the output of the webpack config:

```
output: {
    path: __dirname + '/__build__',
    filename: '[name].js',
    chunkFilename: '[id].chunk.js',
    publicPath: '/__build__/'
  },
```

I can see that all the output files are put under `/__build__` directory. In huge-apps/index.html file, I can see it load the javascript files as below:

```
<script src="/__build__/shared.js"></script>
<script src="/__build__/huge-apps.js"></script>
```

But I couldn't find the `__build__` directory under the entire react-router project. And I couldn't find the `shraed.js` and `huge-apps.js` file either. I am confused about where webpack put these files. From the inspect on browser I can see it loads the javascript files from [http://localhost:8080/**build**/huge-apps.js](http://localhost:8080/__build__/huge-apps.js). Are they in memory only?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The React Router examples use [webpackDevMiddleware](https://github.com/webpack/webpack-dev-middleware) to handle requests to `__build__` resources, which serves files from in-memory.

From [`server.js`](https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/blob/v3.0.0/examples/server.js#L10-L15):

```
app.use(webpackDevMiddleware(webpack(WebpackConfig), {
  publicPath: '/__build__/',
  stats: {
    colors: true
  }
}))
```

Comment: Is there a way to configure it to load js from dist instead of memory?

Comment: You could call `webpack` from within the `examples` folder in order to compile the apps, and then modify `server.js` to serve static content for urls with the `/__build__` path (something like `app.use("/__build__", express.static("/__build__/"));`, but I haven't tested that out).

Answer (score 0):

If you are running webpack indevelopment mode all the file get loaded in memory. to create the file in you need to add "*ExtractTextPlugin*" plugin in webpack

```
 output: {
    path: __dirname + '/__build__',
    filename: '[name].js',
    chunkFilename: '[id].chunk.js',
    publicPath: '/__build__/
  },

  plugins: [
     ....
    new ExtractTextPlugin("[name].css"),
   ...
  ],
```